# Angular - Datatable defaultContent

Tags: angular

I create a datatable in angular with help of [this package](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started). I want to full empty colums with "-".

Suppose that i have a datatable like this

[image]

I want to detect empty columns and fill it with default content. I found  **defaultContent** property but doesn´t work.

So the question is: Using this package how can i fill it empty columns with "-" string?

**UPDATE**: Add defaultContent. No works.

```
this.dtOptions = {
      order: [[0, "desc"]],
      pagingType: "full_numbers",
      pageLength: 10,
      sScrollX: "100%",
      responsive: true,
      processing: true,
      searching: true,
      defaultContent: "-", //I TRY THIS
      language: {...}
}
```

Comment: can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `||` Operator for this purpose, no need for any other library

e.g:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let person of persons">
    <td>{{ person.id || '-' }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.firstName || '-' }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.lastName || '-' }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here it will check if person  dont has the specific attribute then it will just show `-`

**OR**

You can add `columns` with `defaultContent` in your options as:

```
columns: [
  {
    title: 'ID',
    data: 'id',
    defaultContent: '-'
  },
  {
    title: 'First name',
    data: 'firstName',
    defaultContent: '-'
  },
  {
    title: 'Last name',
    data: 'lastName',
    defaultContent: '-'
  }
]
```

Reference: https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/237

Comment: Know this way but i search a more "automatic" way

Comment: actually you have to write these fields manually in html file so whats more effort in putting these `||` ? i would understand if these were generated automatically

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre i updated my answer please check